# dispatch_io_read a socket will wait for more data if receiving data size is smaller than length

Tags: ios, sockets, grand-central-dispatch

Hi I am using `dispatch_io_read` with a socket in swift 2 on Xcode 7 Beta3. It looks like the read action will hold there when the expected receiving data size is smaller than the length I specified. For example,

If I do

`dispatch_io_read(channel!, 0, 1000, inputQueue!, myReadHandler)`

and the data from the server is less than 1000 bytes, `myReadHandler` will never get called.

To solve this, I have to do read bytes one by one, is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: can you set the watermark to 1 using dispatch_io_set_low_water(channel!, 1) before calling dispatch_io_read on the channel

Comment: Yeah, I think it is doable and one way of doing it. I ended up writing the logic to read the exact number of bytes based on the information in the header (first 2 bytes). Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is a little late, but for anyone who has the same problem
[apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1388941-dispatch_io_read) shows that..

"The length parameter indicates the number of bytes that should be read from the I/O channel. Pass `SIZE_MAX` to keep reading until EOF is encountered (for a channel created from a disk-based file this happens when reading past the end of the physical file)."

So, simply using SIZE_MAX will read all the available data attached to the file descriptor.

Unfortunately, this seems to not work due to a bug in Swift 3 with DispatchIO.read().

Comment: As of Swift 4.2 `DispatchIO.read(offset:length:queue:ioHandler:)` still has the bug, namely that the `length` parameter is of type `Int` not `UInt`. Mercifully it is possible to work around this issue by passing `Int(bitPattern: SIZE_MAX)` which will be bit-wise equal to `SIZE_MAX` so when the underlying `C` code reads this param as `size_t` it will equal `SIZE_MAX`.